# TinyMCE button UI weirdness

Tags: tinymce

Anyone encountered this before:

[image]

I've tried using firebug to spot differences between this and a working version and I spot none.

A working version should like the following:

[image]

Comment: Just so everyone is clear, I want to get rid of the extra padding between the buttons.

Comment: This *must* be one of padding, letter-spacing, or margin. Can you post a link?

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot post a link. I'll provide an edit with some css.

Comment: What I find interesting that the splitter lines follow a different rule than the icons. Maybe the images or the surrounding containers have a `width` forced upon them by some other definition elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the CSS classes in your site is conflicting with the TinyMCE classes, and it is causing this problem.  If you are using FireBug then look at the CSS break down on the right and side and see if there is any differences with any of the buttons and their parents.

Comment: I figured it was something stupid and it was...  #Main table { padding:0; margin:0; width:100%; }  Commented that line out in my css and all is good now.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use FireBug** but chrome or safari dom inspectors.
Because firebug and TimyMce don't really work together.